# Cannot save Data to Firebase from HTC android device! WHY?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving data to Firebase Realtime Database. When it comes to HTC 820 the data is not sending to Firebase Database.

1. Everything works fine with Samsung devices from version 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) till 7.0 (Nougat).
2. Tested an `.apk`  on HTC 10 which has android version 7.0, the app is working and data is saved in Firebase Database.
3. But, when tested an `.apk` on HTC 820 it is not saving a data to Firebase Database. To understand the problem, used `Log.d()` and in `Logcat` it represented the data which is sending from the device.

Did anyone had similar issue like this?

Comment: Is this a similar issue: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/1666s2ddpp/firebase-unable-to-authenticate-users-with-firebase-using-email-and-password-on-android ?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, what do you think is, can be done to overcome this device discrimination?

Comment: it can be caused by old version of Google Play Services

Comment: If it was about the version of google play services, it would not have worked in other android devices

Comment: Is your app using g+/fb sigin?

Comment: No, it only uses SMS signing

Comment: IS the data from the database being downloaded on the HTC 820?

Comment: No, look! I have 5 edittexts. (Name, Surname, gender, Age, and telephone) when a user fills all these edittexts, the data should be saved to firebase database. it is working when I use all samsung devices. even htc other than 820. but, when to use HTC 820 device, that data is not uploaded and saved on firebase database. don't know the reason. but i need this solution. searched whole one week, still no results.

Comment: I understand the problem. I just want to know wether the other Firebase database related functions are working or not

Comment: @Zoffa Why are you so sure it's not related to Google Play Services? Have you checked the GPS version on all those devices and can you confirm that it's running the same version?

Comment: Sure, technically Firebase doesn't need GPS to work, but for now it's a dependency that is necessary. I don't mean the google services library version you put in your gradle file, also not the firebase version, but the actual APK on your HTC device. That seems like the most probable cause for now

Comment: Please check that your google play service in your HTC 820 is updated

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Google Play Service before the access to the Firebase to verify if the google play service is updated or if your device is supported or not using this code:

```
public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode,9000).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("error", "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```